# Run jquery plugin with javascript onclick method

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, checkbox

I am using a Jquery plugin for my checkboxes the page of the plugin is this: http://fronteed.com/iCheck/#skin-line

The thing is I used a Javascript function for adding new checkboxes:

```
function add(){

        var userInput = document.getElementById('reg').value;
        document.getElementById('checklist').innerHTML = document.getElementById('checklist').innerHTML +
        "<li> <input type='checkbox'> <label>"+ userInput + "</label> </li>";
    }

    $(document).ready(function(){
      $(' input').iCheck({
        checkboxClass: 'icheckbox_polaris',
        radioClass: 'iradio_polaris',
        increaseArea: '-10%' // optional
      });
    });
```

my HTML where I'm executing the function looks like this:

```
<p><input type="button" onclick="add()" class="bttns" value="Add"/></p>

  </div>
  <h3>Added:</h3>
</div>
<div class="scrollpersonalizado">
       <ul class="listacheck-radio" id="checklist">

          </ul>
  </div>
```

the problem is if I have checkboxes within the:

```
<ul class="listacheck-radio" id="checklist">

</ul>
```

when the page loads, they have the style of the plugin, but whenever I click the button and add a new checkbox, this one doesn't get the style of the plugin, and the ones that were there before stop working.

Can anybody please help?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: maybe you could create a fiddle for this on jsfiddle? just to see the full html and not the examples which you've linked

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to do two things:

1. Stop resetting the entire `.innerHTML` because that wipes out all objects in that sub-hierarchy and creates all new ones (losing all event handlers and styling).
2. Dynamically create your new elements and use on of the `.append()` methods and then call `.iCheck()` on them after creating in order to inherit the new functionality.

Code to do both of those using jQuery:

```
function add() {
    var userInput = $("#reg").val();
    $("<li> <input type='checkbox'> <label>"+ userInput + "</label> </li>")
        .appendTo("#checklist")
        .find("input")
        .iCheck({
            checkboxClass: 'icheckbox_polaris',
            radioClass: 'iradio_polaris',
            increaseArea: '-10%' // optional
         });
}
```

Conceptually, this is what this code does:

1. Get the reg value.
2. Create a new HTML fragment using the reg value
3. Append that to the end of the existing checklist
4. Find the new input tag in that new HTML fragment
5. Call `.iCheck()` on it to bless it with the desired behaviors/styles like the other ones.

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.scrollpersonalizado').on('click', 'input', function(){
       var userInput = document.getElementById('reg').value;
       $('#checklist').append("<li> <input type='checkbox'> <label>"+ userInput + "</label> </li>");
  }).iCheck({
    checkboxClass: 'icheckbox_polaris',
    radioClass: 'iradio_polaris',
    increaseArea: '-10%' // optional
  });
});
```

---

remove the inline `onclick` handler from the `button` try unobtrusive this way with event delegation as you have created your inputs dynamically.

Comment: The whole `obj.innerHTML += "more HTML"` concept is an anti-pattern, recreating objects and event handlers and layout that simply doesn't need to be done.  There's really nothing good about it.  Create new DOM objects and append them to the existing DOM sub-tree, leaving the prior objects untouched.

Comment: @jfriend00 actually i was posting the same as yours but saw your post and changed to this one as another option which might be considered.

Comment: @jfriend00 yes i got what you said updated to append.